# provide mp4 file as camera input

Tags: video, io

Is it possible to have a pre-recorded video on a external storage unit and connect the storage unit as a camera and stream the pre-recorded video as output from the storage unit?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "connect the storage unit as a camera".  You would normally connect as a disc, and you can stream from there, just as from any other disc.

Comment: could it be recognised as a camera input so eg skype could recognise it as a video input device

Comment: I half-see what you mean, but I have no idea how you would use pre-recorded video in Skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible?  Probably.  Is there an easy way to do it?  Probably not.  The problem is that a "storage unit" is not a camera, it is a storage device - they arent the same thing.  There would have to be hardware and/or driver modifications to allow the computer to think the storage is a camera.